# How to anchor for dynamic size/location C#

Tags: c#, location, autosize

I don't know how to ask so this is the example:

[image: auto-size]

So my question is how to avoid two buttons overlapping each other ? How do i need to anchor them or to make the location dinamic ?

In the example both buttons are anchored left,top,right. I need them to auto-size when i maximize.

Answer (score 0):

Put them in a panel docked left and right. Dock them both to fill but dock the right button first.

Answer (score 0):

Using the [Anchor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.anchor.aspx) property of the controls the way you did it should work and is the simplest way to achieve the desired effect. Just make sure you first size and position **both** buttons the way you want them in the designer (so that they just look right in the designer) and then set the anchor of **both** buttons to left **and** right **and** top. They will then resize and reposition themselfes proportionally when you resize the form.

Alternatively you can put the two buttons on a [TableLayoutPanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tablelayoutpanel.aspx) with two columns or on a regular [Panel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.panel.aspx) and use the [Dock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.dock.aspx) property, dock one button to the left and one button to the right.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you want them to each have equal sizes, try putting them into a table, so that each column of the table is 50% width. Then set the table to be anchored left, right, and top.